# Explicitly telling GCC 9.2 to unswitch loop to allow auto-vectorization

Tags: c, for-loop, gcc, vectorization, auto-vectorization

I am working on a project that requires automatic vectorization of large loops. It is mandatory to use GCC to compile. A minimum case of the problem could be the following:

```
#define VLEN 4
#define NTHREADS 4
#define AVX512_ALIGNMENT 64

#define NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS 5

#define real double

typedef struct private_data {
    /*
     * Alloc enough space for private data and MEM_BLOCK_SIZE bytes of padding.
     * Private data must be allocated all at once to squeeze cache performance by only
     * padding once per CPU.
     */
    real *contiguous_data;

    /*
     * Pointers to corresponding index in contiguous_data.
     */
    real *array_1;
    real *array_2;
} private_data_t;

private_data_t private_data[NTHREADS];

int num_iter;

void minimum_case(const int thread) {

    // Reference to thread private data.

    real *restrict array_1 =
        __builtin_assume_aligned(private_data[thread].array_1, AVX512_ALIGNMENT);

    real *restrict array_2 =
        __builtin_assume_aligned(private_data[thread].array_2, AVX512_ALIGNMENT);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS; ++k) {

            int array_1_entry =
                (k * (NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS) * VLEN) +
                i * NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS * NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS * VLEN;

            int array_2_entry =
                (k * (NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS) * VLEN) +
                i * NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS * VLEN;

#pragma GCC unroll 1
#pragma GCC ivdep
            for (int j = 0; j < VLEN; j++) {

                real pivot;

                int a_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 0 + j;
                int b_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 1 + j;
                int c_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 2 + j;
                int d_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 3 + j;

                int S_idx = array_2_entry + VLEN * 0 + j;

                if (k == 0) {

                    pivot = array_1[a_idx];

                    // b = b / a
                    array_1[b_idx] /= pivot;

                    // c = c / a
                    array_1[c_idx] /= pivot;

                    // d = d / a
                    array_1[d_idx] /= pivot;

                    // S = S / a
                    array_2[S_idx] /= pivot;
                }

                int e_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 4 + j;
                int f_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 5 + j;
                int g_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 6 + j;
                int k_idx = array_1_entry + VLEN * 7 + j;

                int T_idx = array_2_entry + VLEN * 1 + j;

                pivot = array_1[e_idx];

                // f = f - (e * b)
                array_1[f_idx] -= array_1[b_idx]
                                  * pivot;

                // g = g - (e * c)
                array_1[g_idx] -= array_1[c_idx]
                                  * pivot;

                // k = k - (e * d)
                array_1[k_idx] -= array_1[d_idx]
                                  * pivot;

                // T = T - (e * S)
                array_2[T_idx] -= array_2[S_idx]
                                  * pivot;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this specific case, GCC is using 16B vectors instead of 32B ones for automatic vectorization. It is fairly easy to see that the control flow depends on a condition that can be checked out of the internal loop, but GCC is not performing any loop-unswitching.

The loop unswitching can be done manually, but please, note that this is a minimum case of the problem, the real loop has hundreds of lines and performing manual loop-unswitching would result in a lot of code redundancy. I am trying to find a way to force GCC to create different loops for different conditions that can be checked out of the internal loop.

Currently I am using GCC 9.2 with the following flags: `-Ofast -march=native -std=c11 -fopenmp -ftree-vectorize -ffast-math -mavx -mno-avx256-split-unaligned-load -mno-avx256-split-unaligned-store -fopt-info-vec-optimized`

Answer (score 0):

Especially if the real loop has hundreds of lines I strongly recommend factoring that out into a separate function -- which then would make manual unswitching (where necessary) not that bad.

The following should be equivalent to your code (notice, I also factored out some index calculations -- this could actually be simplified even more):

```
inline void inner_loop(real *restrict array_1, real *restrict array_2,
                       int const first) {
#pragma GCC unroll 1
  for (int j = 0; j < VLEN; j++) {
    int a_idx = VLEN * 0 + j;
    int b_idx = VLEN * 1 + j;
    int c_idx = VLEN * 2 + j;
    int d_idx = VLEN * 3 + j;

    int S_idx = VLEN * 0 + j;

    if (first) {
      real pivot = array_1[a_idx];

      array_1[b_idx] /= pivot;      // b = b / a
      array_1[c_idx] /= pivot;      // c = c / a
      array_1[d_idx] /= pivot;      // d = d / a
      array_2[S_idx] /= pivot;      // S = S / a
    }

    int e_idx = VLEN * 4 + j;
    int f_idx = VLEN * 5 + j;
    int g_idx = VLEN * 6 + j;
    int k_idx = VLEN * 7 + j;

    int T_idx = VLEN * 1 + j;

    real pivot = array_1[e_idx];

    array_1[f_idx] -= array_1[b_idx] * pivot;    // f = f - (e * b)
    array_1[g_idx] -= array_1[c_idx] * pivot;    // g = g - (e * c)
    array_1[k_idx] -= array_1[d_idx] * pivot;    // k = k - (e * d)
    array_2[T_idx] -= array_2[S_idx] * pivot;    // T = T - (e * S)
  }
}

void minimum_case(const int thread) {
  // Reference to thread private data.

  real *restrict array_1 =
      __builtin_assume_aligned(private_data[thread].array_1, AVX512_ALIGNMENT);

  real *restrict array_2 =
      __builtin_assume_aligned(private_data[thread].array_2, AVX512_ALIGNMENT);

  for (int i = 0; i < num_iter; i++) {
    real *array_1_i =
        array_1 + i * NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS * NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS * VLEN;
    real *array_2_i = array_2 + i * NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS * VLEN;

    inner_loop(array_1_i, array_2_i, 0);
    for (int k = 1; k < NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS; ++k) {
      int array_1_entry = (k * (NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS)*VLEN);

      int array_2_entry = (k * (NUM_INTERNAL_ITERS)*VLEN);
      inner_loop(array_1_i + array_1_entry, array_2_i + array_2_entry, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Full demo on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/wMgSnr

Comment: With the addition of `static inline __attribute__((always_inline))` to the inner loop function, the solution worked out pretty well. However, I would prefer to avoid auxiliary functions, since, in my particular case, they break code evenness. The ideal solution for me would be to make GCC understand that it can make different loops for different conditions.